# How to get the ID token in trigger functions of AWS Cognito?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, amazon-cognito

In the lambda trigger functions of AWS Cognito, say `Post confirmation trigger` or `Post authentication trigger`, I would like to get the ID token, such that I could query some other services on behalf of the user.

Is that possible and if so, how?

It would be terrific if you could also provide a small example in Javascript and/or Python.

Answer (score 0):

The confirmation flow does not generate a user token at all, and the post-trigger for the authentication flow is triggered in parallel with the process that generates and signs the token. It doesn't see the token and has no effect on the token generation, even if it fails.

The ID token, by definition, confirms your users's identity. The idea is that the token is given to the user agent (a browser, or a mobile app, or whatever), and it, being the *user agent*, uses it to do whatever need done on the user's behalf, carrying full responsibility for its actions. If the token ends up in the wrong place (or in the right place), we can be sure that whatever chain of events led to that, it started with the user agent.

Usage of the token by a third party (which is not the user agent) would violate this principle.

If the services that you want to query on behalf of the user are in AWS, you can just assume an appropriate IAM role in the trigger and do what you need done.

If they are third-party services, you'll need generate a separate token. You can do it by calling `AdminInitiateAuth` (but this would trigger MFA if the user has it set up, which, come to think of it, is only fair), or authenticate the trigger otherwise (by using a shared key, or a long-term access token, or something, provided by these services)

Finally, you can implement this logic by having the user agent call an API Gateway endpoint or something, providing the token it just received. This would require an additional roundtrip, which takes time (and can fail).

Again, if you are generating a token for a user agent, the user agent should always be the one presenting the token in the first place. Your trigger is a separate entity and has to provide its own credentials.